# Выбор минимального и максимального значения с учетом порядковых чисел

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица:

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id | column1 | column2 |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 |       5 |       7 |
|  2 |       3 |       5 |
|  3 |      10 |      14 |
|  4 |      12 |      15 |
+----+---------+---------+
```

Мне нужно выбрать минимальные(column1) и максимальные(column2) значения по колонкам, НО с условием, что при пропуске порядковых чисел будет формироваться отдельная запись.

Запрос `SELECT MIN(column1), MAX(column2) FROM test`, выберет минимальное и максимальное значение 3 и 15. Такой результат не годится, потому что важно понимать, что внутри этой выборки есть пропуски чисел: 8 и 9. Таким образом, в этом примере, выбрать нужно числа от 3 до 7 и от 10 до 15 в две записи.

Необходимо получить интервалы. Т.е. результатом выборки должна получиться таблица:

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id | column1 | column2 |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 |       3 |       7 |
|  3 |      10 |      15 |
+----+---------+---------+
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Уточните версию сервера. 5+ или 8+?

Comment: @Akina, Версия 5+ . Но и для версии 8+ интересно было было!

Comment: Идея. Валим всё в кучу, для column1 вес +1, для column2 соответственно -1. Считаем сумму для каждой точки. Точки с суммарным весом =0 - концы, суммарным весом  >0 непосредственно после концов (или null) - начала. Для 8+ это делается в CTE, на 5+ придётся возиться с подзапросом и, вероятно, переменными.

Comment: В принципе, стандартная задача на объединение интервалов.

Comment: @Akina, наверное проще на PHP сделать.

Comment: так у вас в примере отсутствует еще и 4, 6, 11, 13. тогда еще разбивать хотите или как?

Comment: @Denis 4, 6, - отсутствует, но есть минимальное число 3 и максимальное 7 куда входят указанные числа. Также и с 11 и 13 - эти числа входят в интервал от 10 до 15.

Comment: Написали бы в _тексте вопроса_ что требуется получить интервалы. Без комментария Akina я бы не догадался. А вообще @Akina прав, лучше решайте эту задачу не в mysql а в том языке, из которого вы его вызываете. На обычном ЯП это на порядок проще, чем SQL-запросом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column - длинно. Обошёлся `С1` и `С2`.

```
SELECT t3.c1, MIN(t4.c2) c2
FROM (SELECT t1.c1 
      FROM test t1
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                        FROM test t2
                        WHERE t1.c1 > t2.c1
                        AND t1.c1 <= t2.c2)) t3,
     (SELECT t1.c2
      FROM test t1
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                        FROM test t2
                        WHERE t1.c2 >= t2.c1
                        AND t1.c2 < t2.c2)) t4
WHERE t3.c1 < t4.c2
GROUP BY t3.c1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6d46b3cef854767eccab1d133d41c4b1)

Comment: Браво! Спасибо!

Comment: Однако, исходя из множества подзапросов, несмотря на такой элегантный способ, быстрее будет наверное сделать один запрос и разобрать всё в PHP.

Comment: @Pavel Попробуйте на реальном массиве... вполне допускаю, что Вы удивитесь.